# Determining the amount of lag in an autoregressive model

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive

I have done a lot of work in regression (time-invariant) but I am just now studying forecasting.  My question is about determining the amount of lag to use in an autoregressive model.  I assume that in forecasting you use your data up to time t to train your model and then do an out-of-sample test on the data after time t to test your model's performance.  Is there such a thing as overfitting in autoregressive models? That is, using too much lag such that the model does not generalize well to out-of-sample data.  Or is it that you stop seeing an improvement in performance after a certain number of lags?

Comment: There is usually a lot of overfitting, so your question is very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you'd use the [Box-Jenkins methodology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Jenkins) to figure the proper number of AR terms.

Remember, each lagged term has a coefficient, so each term you add is more-or-less diminishing the coefficients of all the other terms. In addition, you're going farther and farther back in time, and more recent terms will tend to affect the future more than ancient terms. So there's a natural tradeoff between more terms and more recent terms.